# Find global minimum (SciPy) and display it on 3D graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, jupyter-notebook

I have a function with two variables and I need to find a global minimum. Also, build the 3D graph and show a global minimum (one point) on the graph. But I'm getting a whole second figure instead of a point. I use Jupyter Notebook. My code is:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
axes = fig.gca(projection='3d')

def f(x, y):
    return (np.exp(np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)))

y = x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 50)

x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = f(x,y)

# optimization
optimize.minimize(f, -3, args=(3)) # maybe something is wrong right here
optimization = optimize.minimize(f, -3, args=(3))


surf = axes.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap='coolwarm',linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

surf1 = axes.plot_surface(x, y, f(optimization.x,y), cmap='coolwarm',linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

axes.set_xlabel('Ось X')
axes.set_ylabel('Ось Y')
axes.set_zlabel('Ось Z')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you optimize your surface among one axis only resulting to another surface plot in your script.

You can find a solution by optimizing iteratively each axis. In the solution I provided below, it works for your example, but finding a global optimum for more complex function (i.e not convex) will required more iterations to converge. (and probably [more subtle gradient descent method](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/lci/mlrg/slides/non_convex_optimization.pdf))

Note that I used contour3D instead of plot_surface to better visualize the plotted point.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
axes = fig.gca(projection='3d')

def f(x, y):
    return (np.exp(np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)))

y = x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 50)

x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = f(x,y)


# optimization x
optimization = optimize.minimize(f, [-3], args=(-3,)) 
best_x = optimization.x

# optimization y
optimization = optimize.minimize(lambda x,y: f(y,x), [-3], args=(-3,))
best_y = optimization.x

#surf = axes.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap='coolwarm',linewidth=0, antialiased=True)
surf = axes.contour3D(x, y, z, 50,  cmap='coolwarm',)
axes.scatter3D([best_x], [best_y], [f(best_x, best_y)], s=[100], c="g");


axes.set_xlabel('Ось X')
axes.set_ylabel('Ось Y')
axes.set_zlabel('Ось Z')

plt.show()
```

[image]]